# How to adjust a table for a better looking

Tags: tables, margins

I'm trying to adjust a table for a better looking, here my code and the output

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell}
\usepackage[referable]{threeparttablex}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}

\newcommand{\Risk}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape Risk}}\nolimits}
\newcommand{\CEOPC}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape CEO\_PC}}\nolimits}
\newcommand{\Boardind}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape Board\_ind}}\nolimits}
\newcommand{\OwnP}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape OwnP}}\nolimits}
\newcommand{\OwnF}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape OwnF}}\nolimits}
\newcommand{\lnZ}{\mathop{\textnormal{\slshape lnZ}}\nolimits}

\begin{document}
\centering
 \sisetup{input-symbols={( - )},
 table-align-text-post=false,
     parse-numbers=false,    
     table-format=2.2         
 }  
 \renewcommand\arraystretch{0.9}
 \setlength\tabcolsep{1pt}
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Risk }
\label{tab:min}
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
                l
           *{6}{S[table-format=-2.3]}
                                    }
\toprule
 &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textit{Credit risk (NPLs):}}
                &   \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textit{Insolvency risk (Log Z-score):}}  \\
\cmidrule{2-3}\cmidrule{4-6}
& {\makecell[b]{EQ}}
    & {\makecell[b]{EQ}}
            & {\makecell[b]{EQ}}
                & {\makecell[b]{EQ}}\\                  
& {(1)} & {(2)} & {(3)} & {(4)}        \\
\midrule
Constant
& 5.06             & -44.380\tnote{***}
& 5.104\tnote{***} & -23.011\tnote{***}       \\
& (16.18)          & (12.04)          
& (17.35)          & (4.429)                  \\
\addlinespace
NPL_{it-1}
& 0.23\tnote{***}   &  0.23\tnote{***}  
&                   &                          \\
& (-2.33)            & (-2.33)            
&                   &                          \\
\addlinespace
lnZ_{it-1}
&                   &                      
&  0.51\tnote{***}  & 0.51\tnote{***}         \\
&                   &                   
& (5.83)            & (5.83)                   \\
\addlinespace
CEO\_PC_{it}
& 6.28 \tnote{***}  & 6.28 \tnote{***}  
& 1.02              & 1.02                      \\
& (12.45)           & (12.45)           
& (1.42)            & (1.42)                    \\
\addlinespace
Board\_ind
& -0.302 \tnote{***}  & -0.302 \tnote{***}
& -0.351 \tnote{***}  & -4.194\tnote{**}         \\
& (-2.26)             & (-2.26)             
& (-9.11)             & (-9.11)                  \\
\addlinespace
OwnF
& 172.346\tnote{***}&                    
& 34.885\tnote{***} &                            \\
& (10.328)          &                    
& (4.545)           &                            \\
\addlinespace
OwnP
&                   & 30.974\tnote{***} 
&                   &  7.323\tnote{**}   \\
&                   & (5.803)           
&                   & (3.704)              \\
\addlinespace
CEO\_PC_{it}*OwnF_{i,t}
& 14.358            &                   
& 2.479             &                       \\
& (14.103)          &                   
& (6.961)           &                       \\
\addlinespace
CEO\_PC_{it}*OwnP_{i,t}
&                   & 1.660            
&                   & 6.437                  \\
&                   & (11.014)          
&                   & (7.461)                \\
\addlinespace
Board\_ind_{i,t}*OwnF_{i,t}
& 0.735             &                   
& -1.743            &                        \\
& (10.900)          &                  
& (4.476)           &                        \\
\addlinespace
Board\_ind_{i,t}*OwnP_{i,t}
&                   & -2.939            
&                   & 2.046                   \\
&                   & (7.612)          
&                   & (3.113)                 \\
\addlinespace
 Size 
& -2.203            & -2.939           
& 2.470             & 2.046                   \\
& (10.975)          & (7.612)           
& (4.639)           & (3.113)                 \\
\addlinespace
Capitalization
& -2.203            & -2.939           
& 2.470             & 2.046                   \\
& (10.975)          & (7.612)          
& (4.639)           & (3.113)                \\
\addlinespace
liquidity 
& -2.203            & -2.939            
& 2.470             & 2.046                   \\
& (10.975)          & (7.612)           
& (4.639)           & (3.113)                  \\
Profitability 
& -2.203            & -2.939            
& 2.470             & 2.046                    \\
& (10.975)          & (7.612)           
& (4.639)           & (3.113)                 \\
Efficiency
& -2.203            & -2.939            
& 2.470             & 2.046                     \\
& (10.975)          & (7.612)          
& (4.639)           & (3.113)                \\
Leverage ratio 
& -2.203            & -2.939            
& 2.470             & 2.046                   \\
& (10.975)          & (7.612)           
& (4.639)           & (3.113)                  \\
Loan growth 
& -2.203            & -2.939            
& 2.470             & 2.046                   \\
& (10.975)          & (7.612)           
& (4.639)           & (3.113)                 \\
Asset growth 
& -2.203            & -2.939            
& 2.470             & 2.046                    \\
& (10.975)          & (7.612)          
& (4.639)           & (3.113)                 \\
Asset growth 
& -2.203            & -2.939            
& 2.470             & 2.046                    \\
& (10.975)          & (7.612)          
& (4.639)           & (3.113)                  \\
Asset growth 
& -2.203            & -2.939            
& 2.470             & 2.046                     \\
& (10.975)          & (7.612)           
& (4.639)           & (3.113)                  \\
\midrule
Year dummy
& {Yes }            & {Yes }           
& {Yes }            & {Yes }                   \\
R$\tnote{2}$
& {0.546}           & {0.314}          
& {0.178}           & {0.112}                 \\
Adjusted R$\tnote{2}$
& {0.543}           & {0.309}           
& {0.173}           & {0.106}                  \\
Sargan test 
& 146.365           & 101.519           
& 65.110            & 43.686                    \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\begin{tablenotes}[flushleft, para]\footnotesize
 \note: \item[*] $p<$0.1; \item[**] $p<0.05$; \item[***] $p<0.01$
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? "better looking" is quite subjective.

Comment: Please give a fully compilable code.

Comment: `NPL_{it-1}` can not work. Do you want `it-1` to be printed as a subscript here? If so, use `\textsubscript` instead.

Comment: @leandis Yes, but I need also to adjust the  right side margins for a better looking

Comment: Please be more specific. Do you want to equally spread column 4 & 5 within the space of the longer header or do you want to add a linebreak in the long header to make it narrower? Also, why do you use `tabular*` here? Also, why do you declare a total of 7 columns? Your table only seems to need 5 columns.

Comment: Are you aware that your table is currently too large for a single page?

Comment: @leandriis I want to equally spread column 2&3 and 4&5

Comment: @leandriis I have to put everything in one table

Comment: You should use a long table – it overflows in the bottommargin

Comment: @AndréC sorry Fixed, now you can compile the code

Comment: @Bernard the code is fixed, you can compile and see my output, it will be nice if you can modify the code as I could not find a way to improve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some comments and suggestions:

- I've broken up some of the header cells to assure that all four data columns can be equally wide.
- I've switched from a `tabular*` to a `tabular` environment, as typesetting the columns at their natural widths would appear to be the right thing to do.
- I've adjusted almost all arguments of `\sisetup` considerably.
- I've fixed up some of the variable names and replaced `*` with `$\times$`.
- There's no need for the `threeparttable` machinery here. In fact, I would argue that the way you use the `\tnote` instructions in your code constitutes a serious form of mis-use of the `\tnote` macro. For instance, please write either `R$^2$` or `R\textsuperscript{2}`, **not** `R$\tnote{2}$`.
- The final two variables in the table seem to be repeats; I've commented out the corresponding code.
- To economize on vertical space, you could comment out all `\addlinespace` directives.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm,a4paper]{geometry} % set page parameters suitably
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[p]
\sisetup{input-open-uncertainty  = ,
         input-close-uncertainty = ,
         table-space-text-pre    = (,
         table-space-text-post   = ***,
         table-format            = 3.3,
         table-align-text-pre    = false,
         table-align-text-post   = false}

\centering
\caption{Risk} 
\label{tab:min}
\begin{tabular}{@{} l *{4}{S} @{}}
\toprule
  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textit{Credit risk}}
  & \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{\textit{Insolvency risk}}  \\
  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textit{(NPLs)}}
  & \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{\textit{(Log Z-score)}} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(l){4-5}
  & {EQ} & {EQ} & {EQ} & {EQ} \\
  & {(1)} & {(2)} & {(3)} & {(4)} \\
\midrule
Constant
  & 5.06 & -44.380*** & 5.104*** & -23.011*** \\
  & (16.18) & (12.04) & (17.35) & (4.429) \\
  \addlinespace
NPL$_{i,t-1}$
  & 0.23***   &  0.23*** & &   \\
  & (-2.33) & (-2.33)  & &   \\
  \addlinespace
$\ln Z_{it-1}$
  & & &  0.51***  & 0.51*** \\
  & &  & (5.83) & (5.83) \\
  \addlinespace
CEO\_PC$_{it}$
  & 6.28***  & 6.28*** & 1.02 & 1.02 \\
  & (12.45) & (12.45) & (1.42) & (1.42) \\
  \addlinespace
Board\_ind
  & -0.302***  & -0.302*** & -0.351***  & -4.194** \\
  & (-2.26) & (-2.26) & (-9.11) & (-9.11) \\
  \addlinespace
OwnF
  & 172.346***& & 34.885*** & \\
  & (10.328) & & (4.545) &  \\
  \addlinespace
OwnP
  & & 30.974*** & &  7.323**   \\
  & & (5.803) & & (3.704) \\
  \addlinespace
CEO\_PC$_{it}$${}\times{}$OwnF$_{i,t}$
  & 14.358 & & 2.479 & \\
  & (14.103) & & (6.961) & \\
  \addlinespace
CEO\_PC$_{it}$${}\times{}$OwnP$_{i,t}$
  & & 1.660 & & 6.437 \\
  & & (11.014) & & (7.461) \\
  \addlinespace
Board\_ind$_{i,t}$${}\times{}$OwnF$_{i,t}$
  & 0.735    & & -1.743 & \\
  & (10.900) & & (4.476) & \\
  \addlinespace
Board\_ind$_{i,t}$${}\times{}$OwnP$_{i,t}$
  & & -2.939 & & 2.046 \\
  & & (7.612)& & (3.113) \\
  \addlinespace
Size 
  & -2.203 & -2.939 & 2.470 & 2.046 \\
  & (10.975) & (7.612) & (4.639) & (3.113) \\
  \addlinespace
Capitalization
  & -2.203 & -2.939 & 2.470 & 2.046 \\
  & (10.975) & (7.612) & (4.639) & (3.113) \\
  \addlinespace
Liquidity 
  & -2.203 & -2.939 & 2.470 & 2.046 \\
  & (10.975) & (7.612) & (4.639) & (3.113) \\
  \addlinespace
Profitability 
  & -2.203 & -2.939 & 2.470 & 2.046 \\
  & (10.975) & (7.612) & (4.639) & (3.113) \\
  \addlinespace
Efficiency
  & -2.203 & -2.939 & 2.470 & 2.046 \\
  & (10.975) & (7.612)  & (4.639) & (3.113) \\
  \addlinespace
Leverage ratio 
  & -2.203 & -2.939 & 2.470 & 2.046 \\
  & (10.975) & (7.612) & (4.639) & (3.113) \\
  \addlinespace
Loan growth 
  & -2.203 & -2.939 & 2.470 & 2.046 \\
  & (10.975) & (7.612) & (4.639) & (3.113) \\
  \addlinespace
Asset growth 
  & -2.203 & -2.939 & 2.470 & 2.046 \\
  & (10.975) & (7.612) & (4.639) & (3.113) \\
%  \addlinespace
%Asset growth 
%  & -2.203 & -2.939 & 2.470 & 2.046 \\
%  & (10.975) & (7.612) & (4.639) & (3.113) \\
%  \addlinespace
%Asset growth 
%  & -2.203 & -2.939 & 2.470 & 2.046 \\
%  & (10.975) & (7.612) & (4.639) & (3.113) \\
\midrule
Year dummy     & {Yes} & {Yes} & {Yes} & {Yes} \\
R$^2$          & 0.546 & 0.314 & 0.178 & 0.112 \\
Adjusted R$^2$ & 0.543 & 0.309 & 0.173 & 0.106 \\
Sargan test    & 146.365 & 101.519 & 65.110 & 43.686 \\
\bottomrule
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{5}{@{}l}{* $p<0.1$; ** $p<0.05$; *** $p<0.01$}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is very professional. Thank you for sharing your expertise..You are always so helpful. your suggestions have also solved the problem of including the negative numbers between brackets !!

Comment: @haithem - You're most welcome! Incidentally, to handle the negative numbers properly, I had to get rid of the option `parse-numbers=false` which you had specified in your code.

Comment: Hi, when using \documentclass[preprint,12pt,authoryear]{elsarticle}
the table do not fit the page .. any solution please

Comment: @haithem - Some suggestions, in no particular order: (a) comment out (or delete) all `\addlinespace` directives; (b) don't show both R^2 and adjusted R^2; (c) switch to 10pt; (d) comment out (or delete) the `& {EQ} & {EQ} & {EQ} & {EQ}` row; (e) insert a `\small` directive near the top; (f) switch from a `table`/`tabular` setup to a `longtable` setup; (g) don't show the coefficients and standard errors of any of the control variables. (For sure, don't devote an entire row to mention that the regressions include year dummies.) If this were my own paper, I'd start with suggestion (g).